# Returning an array of pointers to `char`

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

This program should concatenate strings, But I don't know how return the string array back to main.

```
char **conca(char *a[], int n)
{

char buff[200];

char **conc[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    strcpy(buff,a[i]);
    strcat(buff,"-");
    int l = strlen(buff);
    *conc[i] = malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*conc[i],buff);
}

return *conc;
```

In `main.c`:

```
char **conca(char *a[], int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Uso: %s <stringa> <stringa> ... <stringa> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int dim = argc - 1;

    int pos = 0;
    char *array[dim];

    for(int i = 1; i <= dim; i++ )
    {
        array[pos] = malloc((strlen(argv[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(array[pos],argv[i]);
        pos++;
    }

    char **f = conca(array, dim);
}
```

The program triggers a segmentation fault (core dump).

How can I print the concatenated string in main?

Comment: The segfault happens because you do not have memory for `*conc[i]` when you copy: `*conc[i] = malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char));`
If you want to return a string you should only use single pointers. Not pointers to pointers.

Comment: Do you want `string1 string2 ... stringn` to `string1-string2- ... -stringn` ?

Comment: You've got any reason not to use `strdup()`?

Comment: Please read [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.) before [write in C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S1fISh-pag).

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect. so that expression is just cluttering the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Answer (score 2):

You need return `char*` instead of array of pointer to `char`.
Like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *join(char *a[], int n, char sep){
    size_t lens[n], total_length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        total_length += (lens[i] = strlen(a[i]));
    }
    total_length += n;//sep * (n-1) + NUL

    char *ret = malloc(total_length);
    char *wk = ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i)
            *wk++ = sep;
        memcpy(wk, a[i], lens[i]);
        wk += lens[i];
    }
    *wk = 0;

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc == 1){
        printf("Uso: %s <stringa> <stringa> ... <stringa> \n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int dim = argc - 1;
    char *concata = join(argv+1, dim, '-');
    puts(concata);
    free(concata);
}
```

Comment: I like the `size_t lens[n]` to allow code to use the fast `memcpy()`.  Perhaps make code tolerant of `n == 0` too with separate test?

Answer (score 0):

Reason of segfault is you can not initialize memory for *conc[i] like that :

```
*conc[i] = malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char))
```

instead you have to do

```
conc[i] = malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char))
```

But you have another problem here. You're declaring the array as a local variable. **conc** is an array of pointers which is stored in conca()'s stack frame, so this is, technically speaking, undefined behavior. The solution is to change **conc** to a char ** and use malloc() to allocate the whole array
(and remember to free it later)

So i modified your char **conca(char *a[], int n) function. so i used **conc instead of array of pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **conca(char *a[], int n)
{

char buff[200];

char **conc = (char **)malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    strcpy(buff,a[i]);
    strcat(buff,"-");

    int l = strlen(buff);
    conc[i]=(char *)malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(conc[i],buff);
}

return conc;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if(argc == 1)
        {
                printf("Uso: %s <stringa> <stringa> ... <stringa> \n",argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }

        int dim = argc - 1;

        int pos = 0;
        char *array[dim];
        int i=0;
        for(i = 1; i <= dim; i++ )
        {
                array[pos] = malloc((strlen(argv[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(array[pos],argv[i]);
                pos++;
                pos++;
        }
        char **f = conca(array, dim);

        for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
        printf("%s",f[i]);

        printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `conc[i] = malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char))` is wrong: you forgot to update the type inside `sizeof`. Please also see [why not to cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `char **`, You should return `char *`.

There is also no error checking on [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm), which is needed since you can return a `NULL` pointer if unsuccessful.

Here is an example that shows this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *join(char *argv[], int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *result;

    if(argc == 1){
        printf("Uso: %s <stringa> <stringa> ... <stringa> \n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    result = join(argv, argc);
    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(result);
    result = NULL;

    return 0;
}

char *join(char *argv[], int n) {
    int i;
    const char *sep = "-";
    char *string;
    size_t strsize = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        strsize += strlen(argv[i])+1;
    }

    string = malloc(strsize);
    if (!string) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for string.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *string = '\0';
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        strcat(string, argv[i]);
        if (i < n-1) {
            strcat(string, sep);
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

Input:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c99 -o concat concat.c

$ ./concat Always check return of malloc
```

Output:

```
Always-check-return-of-malloc
```

Comment: do we need to extend the "`char *p` or `char* p`" debate to include whether the star goes before or after the newline ??

Comment: @M.M I'm not sure what you mean. is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: My code seems to match the second style, is that a bad thing?

Comment: It's very unusual to have `char` on one line then `*join` in the next line

Comment: @M.M changed it. I don't know why, but I've always done that with function headers.

Comment: Use of `strcat()` make `join()` `O(strsize * n)`.  By keeping track of the string end, code could be `O(strsize + n)`.

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly outputs error messages to stderr
4. properly checks for errors
5. includes the proper `#include` statements
6. is appropriately commented
7. contains some the original posted code as comments to highlite where changes were made
8. avoids unnecessary variables
9. displays the resulting concatenated string
10. cleans up after itself

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), realloc(), free()
#include <string.h> // strlen(), strcat()


//char **conca(char *a[], int n);
// function prototypes
char *concat(char *argv[], int argc);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Uso: %s <stringa> <stringa> ... <stringa> \n",argv[0]);
        //printf("Uso: %s <stringa> <stringa> ... <stringa> \n",argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        //return 1;
    }

    char *newCat = concat( argv, argc );

    printf( "%s\n", newCat );
    free( newCat );
} // end function: main


char *concat(char *argv[], int argc)
{

    char *newString = malloc(1);
    if( !newString )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful
    newString[0] = '\0';

    for( int i = 1; i <= argc; i++ )
    //for(int i = 1; i <= dim; i++ )
    {
        char * tempptr = realloc( newString, strlen( newString) + strlen(argv[i])+2 );
        if( !tempptr )
        { // then realloc failed
             perror( "realloc failed" );
             free( newString );
             exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        newString = tempptr;
        //array[pos] = malloc((strlen(argv[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
        //strcpy(array[pos],argv[i]);
        strcat( newString, argv[i] );

        // avoid a trailing '-' in final string
        if( i < (argc-1) )
        { 
            strcat( newString, "-" );
        }
    } // end for

    return newString;
} // end function: concat
```